# Is there a real MacOS LiveCD/DVD/USB?

Tags: macos, pxe

I want to make a non-persistent MacOS system in my Mac. I've searched, but I did not found anything working... Do you have any idea?

Comment: This might exist but wouldn't be legal so nobody here can really help you.

Comment: What is it you are **actually** trying to achieve? A full 'desktop' OS such as macOS isn't suited to being used as a 'LiveCD'-type OS. It needs to be able to write to disk, it has to be able to access your AppleID if needed. It would also run like molasses on anything slower than an HD on USB3 [& I'd call even that 'absolute minimum spec'.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas - there's no legality issue running any macOS on any Mac. If you were to set up such a system, you would be quite within your rights to move it from Mac to Mac at will [assuming you set up the correct T2 rights on each]. The issue is it is completely impractical, unless you want a fully-functional read/write structure, which will evolve over time just the same as your regular internal OS would do.

Comment: You can only create a bootable *installation* media.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas I am not sure in that - if you are a legal OSX user, you can probably re-install to an USB pendrive. Thus, sharing a macos live iso is probably illegal, but sharing a tool/script what creates it for you, is not.

Comment: @peterh - Reinstate Monica Do you have one?

Comment: Nobody has one. See my comments above. It's not that one can't be made, it's that there is absolutely no practical value in having one.

Comment: There seems to be a particular need for me to have one, which leads me to this search result. Starting from some day (about two or three years ago) my Mac Mini started to reboot when using, once a month at first but gradually become once a day or so. In my last attempt last month, I tried to install Catalina, but failed on the first reboot (reboot in the middle of installation for several times). Now I'm having Linux on that Mac Mini, but these days I'm wondering if it was caused by an external HDD enclosure so I wish to try a live CD. Running on installation disk doesn't reboot though.